# remove animate for specific section for fullpage.js

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

im successful on animate opacity 0 to 1 when scroll on each section,but now problem is i want to remove the animate(opacity) for specific section example for last section, any idea to remove it?

```
("#fullpage").fullpage({
            anchors: ['slide1', 'slide2', 'slide3', 'slide4'],
            sectionsColor: ['#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff'],
            navigation: true,
            navigationPosition: 'right',
            scrollingSpeed: 1000,
            onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
                    $('.section.fp-section.fp-table.active').animate({
                        opacity: 0,
                        transition: "opacity 0.4s ease-out",
                    }, 500 );

                    $('.section.fp-section.fp-table[data-anchor="slide'+nextIndex+'"]').animate({
                        opacity: 1,
                        transition: "opacity 0.4s ease-out",
                    }, 1000 );

                    // for specific last section ( i got added the opacity : 1,but it no works)

                    if(index == $("#fullpage .section").length){
                        alert('last div : going out');
                        $('.section.fp-section.fp-table').css('opacity',1);
                    }

                    if(nextIndex == $("#fullpage .section").length){
                        alert('last div : coming in');
                        $('.section.fp-section.fp-table.active').css('opacity',1);
                    }

                // }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Not the solution. But could you remove `transition: "opacity 0.4s ease-out"` because either you do the animation with css or jquery `animate()`, but not one inside the other :D

Comment: oh ya,thanks remind!

Comment: Not the solution. But if you want to create a fading effect you should consider using the [fading extension](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/fading-effect.html), which also works with horizontal slides and asures compatibility with future versions of fullpage.js. You can also turn it off an on whenever you need.